# Delete gap in union resualt

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I run this SQL query:

```
SELECT DFC &"(SLAVE)" AS DFCName, DFCC_S AS DFCC_NEW, OBD_Code
FROM tb_KonzeptDaten
WHERE Control_Mask IN ('0000 0000', '0000 0101', '0000 0100', '0000 0001')
UNION
SELECT DFC  AS DFCName, DFCC AS DFCC_NEW, OBD_Code
FROM tb_KonzeptDaten
```

but as a resualt of this query I see something like this:

[image]

As you see in this image, there is a big gap between *ANWCSmax* and *(SLAVE)* how an I delete this gap. I would like to have something like this: ANWCSmax(SLAVE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the`DFC`column has a fixed size. You could try using`rtrim()`to shorten it:

```
SELECT RTRIM(DFC) &"(SLAVE)" AS DFCName
```

The column might still come out at it's original length, so you might have to use another rtrim applied on the whole string:

```
SELECT RTRIM(RTRIM(DFC) & "(SLAVE)") AS DFCName
```